# With Wubi how can I install 12.04 and not 12.10

Tags: wubi

I installed 12.10 using Wubi but i found that there were issues with it (really slow and I could not install skype). According to the Ubuntu website when running Wubi you can choose 12.04 or 12.10 but I can not see how

Comment: You said you installed 12.10 then why do you think you can run 12.04 by installing 12.10?

Comment: You are right it does indeed say that you can install 12.10, or the older 12.04, but like you, I am also unable to find a way to accomplish this....

Comment: There's a bug for that website issue (http://pad.lv/1068234) - in the meantime get it at http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ (at the bottom of the page)

Comment: My thanks to les and bcbc for pointing me to the right place. The wubi.exe from the releases area installs 12.04. To clarify i installed 12.10, did not like it, i uninstalled it and wanted to install 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi, type this in Google or another search engine:

```
ubuntu 12.04 wubi installer download
```

Click on the C-Net download to get Ubuntu. This takes you to a working download for Ubuntu 12.04.

Such web-search based techniques are often helpful for downloading Ubuntu files when you are having trouble finding the right file because it's old, or when there is a problem with the Ubuntu website, with your browser or proxy (e.g., due to caching problems), or just a network slowdown somewhere in between.

Just make sure you're only downloading Ubuntu (and any other software) from sites you trust.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to [`http://releases.ubuntu.com/`](http://releases.ubuntu.com/), select the version of Ubuntu you want, and then download the appropriate `Wubi.exe` file at the bottom of the page. (You must scroll all the way down to get to it.)

Alternatively you can download an ISO image for the version you want to install with Wubi, then unpack the ISO image ([7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) will do this) and run the `Wubi.exe` that (along with all the other files therein) was extracted from the ISO.

- Or you can write the ISO to a USB flash drive, or burn it to a CD or DVD, and run `Wubi.exe` from the written USB or burned disc.
- Or, if you have software installed in Windows that lets you mount ISO images as virtual drives (like [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html)), you can mount the ISO and run `Wubi.exe` from the virtual drive. I don't recommend installing such software *just* for this purpose though as the other methods work just as well.